# How to read complete data using QTcpSocket (Qt4.7)

Tags: c++, qt, tcpserver, qt4.7

I created a TcpServer in order to receive data from a client. The client sends a lot of messages and I would like to read them. So far my TcpServer.cpp looks like this :

```
void TcpServer::serverStart()
{
    server = new QTcpServer(this);
    if (!server->listen(QHostAddress("192.168.x.x"), 48583))
    {
        qDebug() << "Not listening";
        server->close();
        delete server;
        return;
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "Listening";
    }

connect(server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(newConnection()));


}



void TcpServer::newConnection()
{

    socket = server->nextPendingConnection();
    qDebug() << "Client connected";

    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(getData()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), socket, SLOT(deleteLater()));
}


void TcpServer::getData()
{

QByteArray buffer;

while (socket->bytesAvailable())
    {
        buffer.append(socket->readAll());
       }
qDebug() << buffer;
    }




void TcpServer::serverStop()
{
    server->close();
    delete server;
}
```

I know my getData function needs a lot more in order to receive everything but I don't understand the steps needed to do that.If someone could give me some pointers I would be grateful !

Comment: What are you using on top of tcp, what is your application layer protocol?

Comment: also Tcp ! I have 2 applications App1 and App2 sending each other messages via Tcp and I try to create a tool between the two apps that would read the messages coming from App1 , do some work on it and then send it to App2.

Comment: That comment does *not* answer "what is your application layer protocol?". You must be doing something on top of TCP, like exchange some structured messages according to some format/specification. *That* is what @ezegoing is asking about. TCP is just the transport protocol, your application must be expecting something else on top of "bytes arriving in the order they were sent" (which is all TCP gives you).

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I'm a beginner in programming, well I don't have a lot of information about the messages but they are structured as a header and containing bytes and I try to only read the header. I don't know if that answer your question ?

Comment: Yes I know that now but it's the project I'm working on for my internship :/ I will work on my programming knowledge and skills  and come back to you when I know what I'm talking about , thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a transport protocol which is stream oriented. Imagine it as being a continuous flow of data. There are no messages defined by TCP yet, because once again it is a continuous flow of data.

I'm taking from your comment that you are not using any application layer protocol. You need an application layer protocol, like e.g. http, which is then defining "messages" and giving you further instructions on how to read a complete message.